# How to print a memory address?

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I've seen on youtube tutorials about pointers that people `printf` the memory address of a variable. The video in question did this in Code:Blocks, and it works there with `%p`, but whenever I try the exact same thing in Geany (VirtualBox) I get a compiling error. Should I try another kind of %letter Linux?

```
      int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
          int var;

          printf("%p\n", &var);

          return 0;
       }
```

I don't need it for an exercise or something, just curiosity (and to better understand the concept of pointers, I guess). 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The error message is that Linux wants me to cast `&var` to a `(void*)` before it can print it. Sorry, I wasn't completely clear: my question is basically, is this a Linux/Windows thing? And why does Windows accept it as they are, while Linux wants me to cast it as a `void`-pointer?

[error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFgZc.png)

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Always a good start is actually _reading_ the error message (and adding it your question!).

Comment: I think you just have to cast `&var` to `void*`.

Comment: `printf("%p\n", (void*)&var);`

Comment: Please provide the EXACT error message, not a paraphrase of it.

Answer (score 5):

The `%p` specifier expects a `void*`, and you're giving it an `int*`. So just cast it:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)&var);
```

If this were a normal function, the conversion from int * to void * would be automatic and would not generate warnings. But since printf() is a variadic function, the conversion has to be explicit. Arguments to variadic functions are not required to be type-checked. However, some compilers know how the standard functions, including printf(), work and will warn about incorrect usage.

Comment: So in Linux, the %p specifier requires a void pointer, but in Windows it doesn't?

Comment: I get a warning from gcc. I routinely compile stuff like this with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror`. The Microsoft compiler may or may not have a warning level that reports this. What is your compile command line on each?

Comment: Some compilers do less type checking than others.  Windows compiler is technically letting through Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: In CodeBlocks, I don't actually use any command line, I just click the "compile and run" button within CodeBlocks. In Linux, I use

Comment: gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic fileName.c

Comment: So many confused comments in this thread. int * to void * conversion is automatic in C, it's completely valid and should not generate warnings.

The likely issue here is that OP is using a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler. In C++, the conversion is not automatic.

Comment: @jforberg This is a variadic function, they dont do auto conversions other than the standard promotions.

Comment: Did he include `stdio.h`? (if the message is actually not related to `void *` ...)\

Comment: Just to note: there is (usually) no way that `printf` can know the type of the arguments beyond the format string. If you say `"%p"`, `printf` will just assume you gave it a void pointer. Only compilers/interpreters can notice such discrepancies. GCC and Clang are better at it than Microsoft's C compiler, but that depends on the compiler flags.

Comment: @jforberg I'm quite new to programming, my teacher just taught me this as a kind of standard compile line for programming in C. Should I be using a different one from gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic fileName.c?

Comment: I included stdio.h and stdlib.h

Comment: @Marieke: I think your gcc compile line is just fine. You might look into beefing up your compile warnings in CodeBlocks, but I'm not familiar enough with that IDE (or Microsoft compile switches) to tell you how.

Comment: @Marieke, I was wrong for the reason explained by Vality. I have edited this answer to highlight the difference between variadic and normal functions in this case, hopefully making it more clear.

Comment: All right, I understand (enough of) what goes wrong for %p now. Thank you! By the way, the reader I got has an exercise with pointers that does the same thing, but with %x instead of %p. This goes wrong in the compiler within Geany already, but not in the one from CodeBlocks. Is this also just a sign of the compiler in CodeBlocks not being very good?

Comment: `%x` is not for use with pointer values. It might "work", but not if pointer and int are different sizes.

Comment: I thought so too, but the thing is, CodeBlocks makes it seem like it does work. Moral of the story: don't use CodeBlocks if you can use Linux?

Comment: @Marieke: If the conversion specifier and argument types don't match in a `printf` statement, the behavior is *undefined*.  Compilers are not required to issue a diagnostic for undefined behavior.  Also, one possible manifestation of undefined behavior is that your code works as expected.  The only moral here is that you need to a) crank up your warning levels as high as possible, whatever compiler you are using, and b) learn what types go with which format specifier.

Comment: @Marieke: It doesn't really have anything to do with CodeBlocks, because CodeBlocks is not a compiler. It is an IDE. It uses a compiler on your system, such as MSVC or gcc.

Comment: Note that using using `"%p"` and `(void*)` may/may not work well with _function_ pointers.   Conversion from a function pointer type to a `void *` as in `printf("%p\n", (void*)main);` is UB by omission.